# Matlab gui callback transfer

Tags: matlab

I want to input a image. then want to process that image and want to give the output by the button click. then give the output to other step and process that pic again and one other button click give output. what should i do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save data as part of your GUI, you have two possibilities.

1) Save it using guidata:

```
handles = guidata(fig);
handles.imagedata = img;
guidata(fig,handles);
```

This will make the `img` variable available as `handles.imagedata`, whenever you load the GUI data from the figure handle `fig`.

2) Save it as user data in an `uicontrol` or another UI element:

You can for example have the button remember the image:

```
set(handles.button,'UserData',img);
```

where the handle for the button is saved in `handles.button`.
You can now retrieve the image by the following line:

```
img = get(handles.button,'UserData');
```

I hope this answers your question!